# Trouble Solving and Plotting Solution to Simple Differential Equation

Tags: python, matplotlib, odeint

I'm trying to solve the differential equation R^{2} = 1/R with initial condition that R(0) = 0 in python. I should get the solution that R'(t) = (3/2 * t)^(2/3) as I get this from mathematica. [Plot of solution to R'[t]^2 = 1/R with initial condition R(0) = 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofVVN.png)

I used the following code in python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sqrt = np.sqrt

# function that returns dy/dt
def model(y,t):
    #k = 1
    dydt = sqrt(1/y)
    return dydt

# initial condition
y0 = [0.0]

# time points
t = np.linspace(0,5)

# solve ODE
y = odeint(model,y0,t)

# plot results
plt.plot(t,y)
plt.ylabel('$R/R_0$')
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

however I get only 0 as I'm apparently dividing by zero at some point [python plot of differential equation R'[t]^2 = 1/R, which is not correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtLC6.png). Could someone point out what I could do to get the solution and plot I am expecting.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your model needs to be changed.I get your equation for the solution would be something like this https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=R%27%28t%29%5E2+%3D+1%2FR

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# function that returns dy/dt
def model(y,t):
    #k = 1
    dydt = 1*y**-1/2
    return dydt
# initial condition
y0 = 0.1

# time points
t = np.linspace(0,20)

# solve ODE
y = odeint(model,y0,t)

# plot results
plt.plot(t,y)
plt.ylabel('$R$')
plt.xlabel('$t$')
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your starting value is 0, which results in the derivative being zero (`y * -1`, or simpler `-y`), which means 0 will get added to your current y-value, thus remaining at zero for the whole integration. Your code is correct, but not your formulation.

I see a 1/R in your link, so use that, e.g. `dydt = 1/y`; which will fail, because it results in division by zero, so *don't start at zero*, because your derivative is not defined there. There also appears to be a square root somewhere, that you imported, but never use.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I managed to not have the actual code I was using. The original model would clearly not have outputted the desired function. I have changed it to what it should be sqrt(1/y), which is equivalent to writing y'^2 = 1/y. This is exactly the function inputted into mathematica, yet somehow python cannot determine the solution. I understand it's because of the zero, but mathematica doesn't run into this problem with the same code.

Comment: @G.P. See the other part of my answer: try not to start at exactly 0.0; that will result in either an `DivisionByZero` exception, or (with NumPy) infinity, when calculating the differential. If I start at e.g. 0.01 or 1e-6, I can reproduce the original (correct) plot your question links to; not with 0.0 as starting value.

Comment: @ 0 0, thank you! That makes a lot of sense. Kind of annoying, but I can live with it.